# Deploying Web API Controller to Production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET MVC application in VS 2010. I added a new Web API Controller to my application. Here is the simple method I am trying to call:

```
 public List<Article> Get()
        {
            using (var db = new HighOnCodingDbEntities())
            {
                var articles = (from a in db.Articles
                               select a).Take(10).ToList();
                return articles; 
            }

        }
```

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I call this method I get "Resource Not Found". I have published the application binary to the production and I believe that is all I need to do.

URL should be: http://www.highoncoding.com/api/articlesapi

ArticlesAPIController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using HighOnCoding.Models;

namespace HighOnCoding.Controllers
{
    public class ArticlesAPIController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public List<Article> Get()
        {
            using (var db = new HighOnCodingDbEntities())
            {
                var articles = (from a in db.Articles
                               select a).Take(10).ToList();
                return articles; 
            }

        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post(string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Works on local machine:

[image]

Comment: How have you defined the route? What URL are you calling? Honestly how do you think we could answer 404 question not knowing these details?

Comment: updated the  question with additional information!

Comment: How's the controller containing this method called?

Comment: I just visit the URL: http://www.highoncoding.com/api/articlesapi and that is it. IT does not display the results.

Comment: Yes, I can see that it does not display any results. That's what we are trying to help you with. So I repeat my question: `How's the controller class containing this method called?`

Comment: I have pasted the complete code for the ArticlesAPIController class in the original question. I do not understand what you mean by "Hows the controller class containing this method called?" ??

Comment: I have attached a screenshot showing that I can successfully call the Web API controller from local host.

Answer (score 2):

In production, ensure that the .NET Framework version for your IIS7 Application Pool for your website is set to .NET 4.0.xxx in integrated mode.

Comment: Seems like the hosting provider currently does not allow the MVC 4 BETA version